# Error: ASSERTION ERROR: Type passed in is not NgModuleType, it does not have 'ɵmod' property

Tags: angular

If i remove @NgModule i get this error.

`Can anyone tell me what is an emod property`.I googled a lot but couldnt find any information on this.Additionally can anyone give me resources which tell what all are injected by angular at run time.Actually i am afraid to ask this.I know this is a stupid question but still in a terrian where angular seems to me a blackbox.

Comment: @erroau i was trying to understand what NgModule does.What would be error when i missed it